# Is it possible to open app in background in iOS (without user interaction)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, launch, iphone-privateapi, background-mode

Is it possible to open an iOS app in the background, without any user interaction?

We can use private frameworks for this.

I don't need to worry about App Store submission, as the app is for enterprise distribution.

Comment: Should the app be started at a specific event, such as when the phone is booted up?

Comment: @newenglander- Thanks for showing interest. The event will be a web service message for example internet connection will be established and from web service the message is received open "Message" App. At that time i need to open the Message app. In this if the App is in foreground then it is possible but if the App is in background, then it is not possible as of now. There will be no such event such as phone is booted up.Please add your comment if you have any clue on this.

Comment: How soon after the web service sends a message should the app react, immediately or could it be after a while? Also, is jailbreak a possibility?

Comment: Btw, you have a 0% answer acceptance rate. You might want to fix this to help motivate others to help you. If an answer isn't helpful, you could add comments as to why this is.

Comment: It should be immediately open the App. No jailbreak, we can only use Private frameworks.

Comment: I will work on accepting the answers. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably implement Location services taking permission for always using

```
let manager = CLLocationManager()
manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

this will wake your app in the background or keep the app alive while location services are on.

or you can use CallKit which will also help keeping your app alive in the background. Since you will not be deploying the app on app store you dont have to worry about the approval from apple.

But none of these will let you launch the app in foreground. Of course if you plan it out you can still do a lot in the background with these frameworks.